# Can we express the continuity of a function in this delta-epsilon form?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

It can be shown that :

If a function $f$ is uniformly continuous, then there exist an increasing function $\epsilon(\delta)$ with $\epsilon(0)=0$ such that $||x_2-x_1||<\delta \Rightarrow ||f(x_2)-f(x_1)||<\epsilon(\delta)$.

I would like to know if this result already exists somewhere (in some book or ...)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I feel like we should have instead $\epsilon (0^+) = 0$.

Comment: Don't you need uniform continuity to build such a function ϵ(δ)  ?

Comment: As @Evargalo states, this is false without *uniform* continuity.

Comment: Thank you! the statement was edited.

Comment: Such a function is called a modulus of continuity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) for $f$.